# react returning my ref undefined when i use it transiontioend event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting my array from state after transitionend event but it's returning undefined
 here's my code I was using this function on a click event but it was returning this.slider.current
     undefined

```
this.state = {
            slides: [{
                    src: slide1,
                    name: "Livingroom1",
                    id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
                },
                {
                    src: slide2,
                    name: "Livingroom2",
                    id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
                },
                {
                    src: slide3,
                    name: "Livingroom3",
                    id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
                },
                {
                    src: slide1,
                    name: "Livingroom4",
                    id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
                },
                {
                    src: slide2,
                    name: "Livingroom2",
                    id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
                },
                {
                    src: slide3,
                    name: "Livingroom3",
                    id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
                }
            ]
        }
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.slider.current.addEventListener('transitionend', function (e) {
        console.log('transitionend', e.propertyName);
        if (e.propertyName === 'transform') {
            if (this.el === 1) {
                var pop = [...this.state.slides];
                pop.pop();
                this.setState({
                    slides: [this.state.slides[5], ...pop]

                });
            } else {
                var shift = [...this.state.slides];
                shift.shift();
                this.setState({
                    slides: [...shift, this.state.slides[0]]

                });
            }
            console.log(this.slider.current);
            this.slider.current.style.transform = 'translate(0)';
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.slider.current.style.transition = 'all 0.3s';
            })
        }

    });

      }
```

Comment: it's returning my slides in state undefined too

Comment: Instead of `function (e) {` try this `(e) => {`